# Laravel collection forPage removed sorting?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am trying to paginate a collection using the length aware paginator like so:

```
new LengthAwarePaginator($cases->forPage($request->get('page'), $per_page), $cases->count(), $per_page, $request->get('page'));
```

Just before this I am sorting the collection by;

```
$cases->sortBy('inactive_percentage', SORT_REGULAR, 'desc');
```

But the result I get from the paginator is not the same. I get low inactive percentages first. If I try the per_page to say 100 which is more than records that exist, then the result is sorted correctly.

How to use the paginator to handle the sorted collection?

Comment: Do you really need to do `forPage` ? I thought that was the paginators job.

Comment: If I have to use it manually, I think I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't post any comments yet... lol Trying to get my rep up a little...

My encounter with a manual paginator ended up me having to slice the array myself... As per the doc :

> When manually creating a paginator instance, you should manually
>   "slice" the array of results you pass to the paginator. If you're
>   unsure how to do this, check out the array_slice PHP function.

Example of one of my manual array pagination controller functions (paginators deal with underlying arrays...)

```
public function comments(){

        // DB::select returns an array, thus we have to build the paginator ourselves...
        $comm = DB::select('select bla bla bla...
                            order by c.approved ASC, c.id DESC ');

        // this basically gets the request's page variable... or defaults to 1
        $page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage('page') ?: 1;

        // Assume 15 items per page... so start index to slice our array
        $startIndex = ($page - 1) * 15;

        // Length aware paginator needs a total count of items... to paginate properly
        $total = count($comm);

        // Eliminate the non relevant items...
        $results = array_slice($comm, $startIndex, 15);

        $comments =  new LengthAwarePaginator($results, $total, 15, $page, [
            'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
            'pageName' => 'page',
        ]);
        return view('backend/comments', compact('comments'));
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yeah, I had to splice it myself in the end so your answer is right. Thanks